# wordpress: override html markup for comment_text

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to customise the comments.php file in a custom theme.

I'm using

```
<?php comment_text(); ?>
```

which seems to output the comment text in `<p></p>` tags. I'm aiming to add the class so that it formats as: `<p class='lead'></p>` (spot the twitter bootstrap css).

Can anyone help me figure out how to customise these tags... i may want to use other ones `<h1>`, etc. I've tried apply_filters but I cant get that to work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Are you talking about the p tag that wraps the comment, or the p tag that gets added to the comment?

You could try replacing

```
<?php comment_text(); ?>
```

With:

```
<p class='lead'><?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?></p>
```

You could also you jQuery to add a class. Just make a wrapper with a class of anything, lets say "comment-wrap".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".comment-wrap p").addClass("lead");
</script>
```

Comment: `<p class='lead'><?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?></p>` worked like a charm! Champion